Start open dialog in gedit in directory of currently open file
Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1. I use gedit as all-purpose text and programming editor. In previous versions, when pressing the Open button, the file picker would start in the directory of the file that was currently open and in focus.
After the upgrade, when gedit has just started from the GUI (either by clicking the Dock icon or by double-clicking a file in Nautilus) then the Open dialog starts in my home directory. If I navigate to another directory in the file picker and open a file, then the next time I click Open within that session it starts from the directory of the last opened file, also when I have a number of files open from different directories and the file that is in focus is in a different directory.
If I start gedit from the terminal (with or without a file) then the first Open dialog will start from the directory from which gedit was started in the terminal.
Other applications that use the same Gnome open dialog (for example Geany) do still have the old behavior also in Ubuntu 24.04 (i.e., start the dialog in the directory of the currently open file), so I believe this is gedit-specific.
So the question is: Is it possible to start the gedit Open dialog always in the directory of the currently open file?

There was a bug about this in https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/gedit/gedit/-/issues/382 , where Gedit always defaulted to $HOME. It was fixed to the behavior you (and everyone) wants. So current behavior is a regression from that fix. I'm also trying to find the very commit / bug report that introduced this current behavior, as it is infuriating! Whoever finds it, please post here!

There you go: https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/gedit/gedit/-/issues/575

This has changed a few times in the last years, and every time this happens, a lot of users (including you and me) gets very disappointed.
For the record, the current behavior was introduced in commit 51937d87313, and there is a bug report asking to revert that and restore the well-known behavior. It has been closed, but maybe if you and enough people chime in they could reconsider.
There were past reports about this behavior too, as mentioned in that bug report.
